# Is it possible to do parallell, rather than distributed, hyperparameter tuning in Google ML Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I would like to let each ML Engine worker independently handle one trial, rather than having them cooperate with each trial (distributed training).

Is this possible?

(When setting `workerCount` > 0 it seems to pass each trial to every worker, independently of the value set for `maxParallelTrial`)

Answer (score 2):

If each trial only requires a single machine, then configure your `TrainingInput` with the requirements for each trial (e.g., workerCount = 0; parameterServerCount = 0) and control the number of parallel trials with `maxParallelTrial`. That should have the desired effect.

Comment: Great, I assumed parallell trials only use the cluster specified and would never duplicate them.